# Nested GridView show child rows by default

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am following [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) link which shows how we can create a nested grid, I was able to complete the tutorial but I am trying to show child grid by default like this in expand mode:

[image]

Here is the Jquery function code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "/images/minus.png");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "/images/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
</script>
```

**Question:** How to  modify this code so that when page is loaded grid will be in expand mode instead of collapse?

Comment: you can trigger click on that plus sign once you have setup your grid in your javascript code

Comment: @Mike, that what i tried but its not working.

Comment: Is it possible for you to make a JSFiddle for it? One more thing is that you are using `live` , which was deprecated since `version 1.7` and removed in `version 1.9`. You can either simply bind `click` event after settting up your grid, or you can use the syntax for binding events to dynamically generated elements e.g.

    `$(document).on('click', '[src*=plus]', function(e){
      // event handling code here
    });`